# How to change ion-header color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am developing ionic application and have strange behaviour.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button ng-click="clickMe()" class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
```

I am planning to have custom background header color. So I changed the code to

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm nav-title-slide-ios7" ng-style="HeaderColor">
            <ion-nav-back-button ng-click="clickMe()" class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
```

Here HeaderColor attribute has an style defined for background color.
Also added -

```
.nav-bar-block .bar {
    background-color:inherit !important;
}
```

Now, I am able to see background color property applied to nav-bar but header is transparent and shows the color of ion-view but not the header.
Example : If my ion-view is green and header is black -- screen displayed is fully green including header.

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: How your `HeaderColor` is set in controller?

Comment: i think your bar-calm is the  responsible class for your case....

Answer (score 1):

add custom style (red in my case):

```
.bar.bar-custom {
    border-color: #f40428;
    background-color: #f40428;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #f40428, #f40428 50%, transparent 50%);
    color: #fff; 
}
```

and HTML:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-custom">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

See <kbd>[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmOWWo)</kbd>

---

you can also change title color as:

```
.bar.bar-custom .title {
      color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works...one quick info.. My background color for header is dynamic and is retrieved from server.. What can be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @Anand its not related to this question, (u welcome to acceept it) Anyways, do you have fixed list of colors? if yes, use `ng-class` and define all styles per class. If no, use `ng-style`. Generally all styling uses one color

Comment: yup.. Agree :).. regd. Query : It's color picker.. So any color can come.. I tried ng-style but background is not applied.. I am adding ng-style to navbar.. I think the  . bar. bar-custom??  How. bar can be achieved here in angular??

Comment: @Anand as I mentioned above this problem is not related to your question. Be sure that new color enters to digest cycle